# Simple python object has no attribute and cannot set queryset as variable

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and django and am receiving the following attribute error:

```
AttributeError at /account/1/
'Account' object has no attribute 'subscribers_set'
```

I don't know why this happens because one account can have many subscribers. In the shell I can run a query for an account that will return all the subscriber objects, e.g. `account.subscriber_set.all()` returns `<QuerySet [<Subscriber: bob@bob.com>, <Subscriber: sally@salhurst.com>, <Subscriber: jessy123@something.com>]>` - but for some reason I can't set the queryset to a variable: trying to set variable with `subscribers = account.subscribers_set.all()` returns error AttributeError: `'Account' object has no attribute 'subscribers_set'`

In my views.py I have this account function:

```
def account(request, id):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=id)
    subscribers = account.subscribers_set.all()  # error here?
    context = {'account': account, 'subscribers': subscribers}
    return render(request, 'accounts/account.html', context)
```

And my view:

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Account Page for {{account}}</h1>
<p>Email Address: {{account.email}}</p>
{% for sub in subscribers %}
    <p>{{subscriber}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('account/<str:id>/', views.account, name="account"),
]
```

The class model is basically just the user model:

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

And there's a one:many relationship between Accounts and Subscribers:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Why is this error occurring, and how can it be fixed? Can you not store querysets in variables in python? I'm a beginner so I assume this is something quite obvious but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I'm noticing straight away are that in your `account()` function, you're reassigning the function name as a variable, and shadowing the inbuilt `id`. You should definitely not do that:

```
def get_account(request, ident):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=ident)
    subscribers = account.subscribers_set.all()  # error here?
    context = {'account': account, 'subscribers': subscribers}
    return render(request, 'accounts/account.html', context)
```

Neither of these are causing the problem though. And you're going to be annoyed at yourself, but looks like there's a spelling error.

- In the shell: `account.subscriber_set.all()`
- In the code: `account.subscribers_set.all()`

One has an extra `s`...

Comment: ah, can't believe the spelling error! thanks

Answer (score 1):

here both those function will give the same result

```
def account(request, id):
  account = Account.objects.get(id=id)
  subscribers = Subscriber.objects.filter(account=account)
  context = {'account': account, 'subscribers': subscribers,}
  return render(request, 'accounts/account.html', context)
  
def account(request, id):
  account = Account.objects.get(id=id)
  subscribers = account.subscriber_set.all()
  context = {'account': account, 'subscribers': subscribers,}
  return render(request, 'accounts/account.html', context)
```

you had it right, you just wrote "subscribers_set" instead of "subscribers_set"